# How to select rows from table based on specific filters in PostgreSQL 11.0

Tags: postgresql

I have following table in `PostgreSQL 11.0`

```
col1            col2          col3                         col4     col5             col6                      
98262898184 NCT01243502       0.01% ct327 (or placebo)     false    placebo term    (null)
98262898184 NCT01243502       0.01% ct327 (or placebo)     false    no mapping      (null)
98262898185 NCT01268527       0.01% e6201                  false    no mapping      (null)  
98262898165 NCT01654484       0.0015% tafluprost           true     (null)          (null)
98263196888 NCT02925793       vehicle cream                false    vehicle term    (null)
98263196888 NCT02925793       vehicle cream                false    no mapping      (null)
```

I would like select those rows where for a common values of `col1, col2, col3` and `col5` value is `placebo term`, `vehicle term` and excluding is counter row.

The desired table is:

```
col1            col2          col3                         col4     col5             col6                      
98262898184 NCT01243502       0.01% ct327 (or placebo)     false    placebo term    (null)
98262898185 NCT01268527       0.01% e6201                  false    no mapping      (null)  
98262898165 NCT01654484       0.0015% tafluprost           true     (null)          (null)
98263196888 NCT02925793       vehicle cream                false    vehicle term    (null)
```

I have no idea at the moment how to get this desired output. Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: what is the logic for col5 value?

Comment: I'm sorry could you reword your question? Maybe try to be more explicit detailing how the desired result could be achieved just in English (no code). In `col5` you have values `no mapping` `null` why are those tuples selected? Could you explain what you mean by `common col1, col2, col3 values`, maybe using your actual table to show the case.?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I understood from your question is you want distinct rows from your table based on `col1, col2, col3` and prefer the row having `col5` value as `placebo term` or `vehicle term`.

Try this:

```
with cte as (
     select * , 
           case when col5='placebo term' or col5='vehicle term' 
           then 1 else 0 
           end as "flag_" 
     from my_table
)

select distinct on (col1,col2,col3) 
               col1, col2, col3 col4, col5, col6 
from cte 
order by col1, col2, col3, flag_ desc
```

[DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=a2e741ebe43c4c4e23afd130e8811faf)